# Bruteforcing a Wi-FI password

Tags: passwords, wifi, brute-force

Is it possible to brute-force a WiFi password, since technically there are no limits with login attempts?

If there is any, the MAC address of the attacker device can be changed.

Comment: There are too many "if" in your question. For example, for some encryption methods it is FEASIBLE for some it is not.

Comment: Of course it is possible to brute force wifi passwords. That's how wifi hacking typically works. What are you really asking?

Answer (score 1):

Brute-forcing a Wi-Fi password, and by extension wireless cracking in general, is a large subject matter in and of itself. **Generally speaking, yes, it is certainly possible to brute-force a Wi-Fi password, but there are many things to factor into the equation.** Namely, the type of encryption that is used on the wireless network will play a large part in the feasibility of such an attack.

As the question posed is quite broad, the answers you receive will be as well.

As a new member to the security exchange myself, I have found it useful to read the articles in the [Help Center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/asking) about ways to formulate my questions more effectively. I think you will get much better results by asking a more specific question. Perhaps try digging into the following [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracking_of_wireless_networks) about wireless cracking that will hopefully generate some more specific questions for you to ask.